# Что такое поток в C++?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Знаю что в C++ нету своих потоков, только реализация через I/O, а там через winapi кажется, но как представлять поток и что это вообще такое и в какой памяти он располагается и в какой момент времени работает или постоянно работает и что такое многопоточность и как её сделать? Вообщем ровным счетом ничего не знаю про потоки, а в книгах ограничиваются парой слов о них и легким примером как пользоваться. Ясно что я ещё очень мало знаю, так как не смогу в исходниках понять что и к чему. Но могли бы вы дать какое-то легкое представление о потоках не требующее низкоуровневых знаний, чтобы хоть на время знать с чем имеешь дело? А то к примеру в ссылках [1](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) сплошной темный лес и ничего не понятно.

Comment: @mzarb, ссылка (1) - это thread, а (2) - stream.

Thread - поток команд процессора.

Stream - поток байт ввода-вывода.

Между ними кроме *русского* слова *поток* нет ничего общего.

Comment: @mzarb, судя по Вашему вопросу 

    Почему нельзя перегрузить оператор << в класcе? 

стоит уточнить, что Вас интересуют в первую очередь **потоки ввода-вывода в С++**.

А то ведь tread-ами замучают (сейчас это модно).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала нужно понять, что в русском языке одним словом «поток» переводят два разных термина. Первое — поток исполнения, он же *thread*, второе — поток данных, он же *stream*.

> Знаю что в C++ нету своих потоков

Неверно. В последнем стандарте потоки исполнения уже есть. А потоки данных там есть уже давно. И то, и другое в конечном счете реализуется через операционную систему.

> но как представлять поток (данных)

Представляйте его в виде дополнительной программы, которая делит общее адресное пространство (и некоторые другие ресурсы) с основной. Общее адресное пространство — это когда указатель с одного потока будет действительным и в другом. С программами же это не так. Если передать значение указателя (например, через сообщения), то он будет указывать непонятно куда (кроме ситуации с `wm_copy_data`).

> в какой момент времени работает или постоянно работает

После того, как поток запустили, он начинает работать до тех пор, пока не завершит свою работу. Для начала считайте, что он исполняется параллельно. Куча запущенных программ, которые работают одновременно, не смущают? С потоками тоже самое. Более того, на самом деле процессы не исполняются — это просто контейнеры. Исполняются потоки. Как следствие, любой процесс имеет хотя бы один поток.

> А то к примеру в ссылках 1 и 2 сплошной темный лес и ничего не понятно.

Разницу я описал выше.

Теперь о том, может поток данных исполнятся. Теоретически — да, если это поток байт, который идет на вход процессора. Но в C++ он может только читаться-писаться.

Как ее делать, если нужен поток данных?

Первым делом нужно создать функцию, которая будет исполнятся в отдельном потоке. Потом вызвать соответствующую функцию операционной системы (`_beginthread`, `CreateThread` и тому подобное). [Вот пример](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540912/Cplusplus-11-Threads-Make-your-multitasking-life-e).

В целом, в Вашем вопросе аккуратно смешаны вопросы о двух типах потоков. Я попытался разделить и в основном ответить о потоках исполнения (*thread*).

Comment: То есть процессы - это адресные пространства с контейнером для потоков выполнения(thread), а потоки данных(stream) - это уже абстрактная сущность языка программирования, которая в конечном итоге становится thread? Я имею ввиду что stream реализованы с помощью thread и есть просто оболочка для удобности в использовании?

Comment: >> То есть процессы - это адресные пространства с контейнером для потоков выполнения(thread)

да

>> а потоки данных(stream) - это уже абстрактная сущность языка программирования,

ну почти абстрактная. пленку в кассетах помните? это тоже поток данных. Ну или лента новостей в вконтакте. Это также stream.

>> которая в конечном итоге становится thread? Я имею ввиду что stream реализованы с помощью thread и есть просто оболочка для удобности в использовании?

нет.

Comment: @mzarb, по сути Вашего вопроса в комментарии, я бы сказал, что stream и thread **никак не связаны**.

Т.е. связи между ними с т.з. логики программирования не больше, чем между регистрами процессора и буферами какого-нибудь контроллера.

 Ведь в реализации и регистров и буферной памяти есть транзисторы (в виде  модифицированных участков кремниевой пластины) и между ними есть определенным образом скоммутированные проводники тока.

Comment: @avp общего между регистрами процессора и буферами контроллера значительно больше.

Answer (score 4):

[тут большое и подробное описание потоков (STREAM) в С++](http://citforum.ru/programming/cpp/gl8.shtml)

---

Потоки **Thread**

сейчас будет сочинение на тему "как я провел студенческие годы". Если я в чем-то ошибаюсь, просьба не агриться, а просто поправить меня.

**ОЧЕНЬ** ГРУБО ГОВОРЯ:

Есть приложение. Когда вы его запускаете, появляется процесс. Процесс - это загруженный в оперативную память экземпляр приложения. Каждый процесс состоит из потоков, можно даже сказать, что процедуры/функции процессов поделены между потоками. Поток может быть один или их может быть несколько. Например, если вы хотите, чтобы при запуске приложения, у вас одновременно рисовался интерфейс и загружались данные из базы, то эти две операции вам нужно будет разделить на два потока - интерфейс будет на основном, а загрузка данных на дополнительном.
**идем дальше**
Какой поток будет выполняться быстрее? На обработку каждого процесса система выделяет процессорное время, в зависимости от приоритета процесса (посмотреть приоритеты Вы можете в диспетчере задач). У каждого потока внутри процесса так же есть приоритет, и по данным приоритетам выделенное процессорное время будет делиться между потоками.

Comment: ссылка описывает немного другие потоки:)

Comment: @KoVadim, да, там потоки данных. Но и у автора в вопросе и потоки данных и потоки процессов. По ссылке я описал одни, а в _сочинении_ другие

Comment: но это же не повод брать пример с ТС и смешать у себя:)

Comment: у меня был полет фантазии :) сначала написал все что помню, а потом отредактировал и разделил :)

Answer (score 4):

Так как упомянут термин "многопоточность", предлагаю еще один вариант "легкого представления" о потоках выполнения.

> как представлять поток и что это вообще такое, в какой момент времени работает

любая Ваша программа представляет из себя последовательность команд, которые обрабатывает процессор, в однопоточной программе - эта последовательность одна на процесс, в многопоточной - их много. Работают они в тот момент, в который Вы им разрешите, т.е. Вы можете запустить много потоков сразу, или они могут запускаться при необходимости по определенным событиям, могут завершаться выполнив возложенные на них обязанности, или же существовать все время жизни программы. Если Вы задаетесь вопросом типа "зачем их придумали, есть же процессы", - ответ следующий : на переключение проецссора между разными процессами тратится много времени из-за того, что процессы обладают собственным простарнством памяти. При переключении между потоками эти издержки значительно меньше, так как потоки разделяют между собой большую часть ресурсов программы. К тому, что каждый из потоков не делит с другими однозначно можно отнести стек (стек процесса делится на количество "содержащихся в нем" потоков, каждому потоку достается свой) и программный счетчик. В общем случае потоки можно представлять как несколько кусоков кода, выполняющихся параллельно в рамках одного процесса.

> в какой памяти он располагается

так как поток выполнения - это по сути кусок кода, то в памяти программ.

> что такое многопоточность и как её сделать

многопоточность - свойство кода программы выполняться параллельно(одновременно) на нескольких ядрах процессора(путем назначения каждому ядру потока выполнения(куска кода, который он должен обработать)) или выполняться псевдопараллельно на одном ядре(каждый поток получает в свое распоряжение некоторое время, за которое он успевает исполнить часть своего кода на процессоре). Распределением потоков по ядрам обычно занимается диспетчер, но при желании в коде программы можно явно привязать поток к какому-либо ядру.

Сделать программу многопоточной можно используя специальные библиотечные функции, например из Boost или Intel TBB. В общем случае:

1. запускаем функцию создания потока и передаем ей код, который поток будет выполнять(указатель на собственную функцию, метод),
2. используем библиотечные функции синхронизации в кодах своих функций/методов

Есть так же более простые способы, например использование API стандарта OpenMP, который дает возможность распараллеливания отдельных кусков кода просто добавлением директив компилятора, но этот метод имеет свои ограничения в применении и подходит не для всех задач.

*данный ответ дает только поверхностное представление о потоках выполнения, как и просили.